# Remove markup in tests

Tags: perl, mojolicious

When I run tests which fail I get a huge output with a lot of markup hiding the error.

Example:

```
$ perl script/my_prove.pl t/2410-topinfo.t 
t/2410-topinfo.t .. 1/? 
#   Failed test '200 OK'
#   at t/2410-topinfo.t line 12.
#          got: '500'
#     expected: '200'

#   Failed test 'similar match for selector "h1"'
#   at t/2410-topinfo.t line 12.
#                   ''
#     doesn't match '(?^:Flatinfo\ Business\-Apartment\ Hietzing)'

#   Failed test 'content is similar'
#   at t/2410-topinfo.t line 12.
#                   '<!DOCTYPE html>
# <html>
#   <head>
#     <title>Server error (development mode)</title>
#     <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
#     <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
#     <script src="/mojo/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
#     <script src="/mojo/prettify/run_prettify.js"></script>
#     <link href="/mojo/prettify/prettify-mojo-dark.css" rel="stylesheet">
#     <style>
#       a img { border: 0 }
#       body {
#
#   ........... lots of lines removed here ...........
#
#     <div id="wrapperlicious">
#         <div id="nothing" class="box spaced"></div>
#         <div id="showcase" class="box code spaced">
#           <pre id="error">Can&#39;t call method &quot;name&quot; on an undefined value at template extern/topinfo/show.html.ep line 2.
# </pre>
# 
#    .... lots of lines follow here ............
```

The error seems to be a single line:

```
 Can't call method "name" on an undefined value at template extern/topinfo/show.html.ep line 2
```

The test-script producing this output is:

```
use Mojo::Base -strict;

use Test::More;
use Test::Mojo;

use FindBin;
require "$FindBin::Bin/../script/ba_db";
my $t = Test::Mojo->new( 'BaDb' );
$t->ua->max_redirects(1);

$t->get_ok('/info/penx2')
    ->status_is(200)
    ->text_like('h1' => qr/\QFlatinfo Business-Apartment Hietzing\E/)
    ->content_like( qr/\QSelected language: German\E/ )
    # ... 
;
done_testing();
```

Is there a way to tell Mojolicious to respond **without** all this HTML-Markup so that I can see the error-mesage immediately?

Answer (score 3):

There are two things at play here.

The large debug output with the full page source is because the [`content_like` method from Test::Mojo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Mojo#content_like) didn't find a match, and it's telling you in which string it was looking. That's a convenience method, but if the page is large, it's a lot of text. This might tell you that the test failed because the content was wrong. But in this specific case it didn't.

The real problem is that the test failed because you had a syntax error. You can already see that from the very first test.

> ```
> $t->get_ok('/info/penx2')
>     ->status_is(200)
> ```

This test also failed. (It's a bit confusing for people who are used to Test::WWW::Mechanize because there `get_ok` will also check if the response was `200 OK`).

> ```
> #   Failed test '200 OK'
> #   at t/2410-topinfo.t line 12.
> #          got: '500'
> #     expected: '200'
> ```

The actual error message should be there without all that HTML markup somewhere else, because while it was doing the `get_ok` it would have encountered the error, which should have gone to the application log. In a unit-test, that probably is STDERR.

I don't know if you've not included it, or if it's omitted. The log should be there too I believe.

---

Getting back to the HTML and the actual question, the reason it's output is because Test::Mojo's `content_like` (and most other of its methods) uses Test::More under hood. [It just dispatches](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-7.35/lib/Test/Mojo.pm#L390) to [`like` from Test::More](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::More#like) and passes along the page content. This in turn will always display the full string it was matching against.

In recent Test::More versions, it already uses Test2 under the hood. The relevant part that outputs the full string is [here](https://metacpan.org/source/EXODIST/Test-Simple-1.302086/lib/Test/Builder.pm#L1115).

Unfortunately there is not much you can do about it. I'd focus on finding out why it doesn't show a proper log during the unit tests (possibly because you didn't run `prove` with `-v`), and maybe find a way to make errors come out in color, which would make it easier to read. There is [a color logger for the Dancer2 framework](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Logger::Console::Colored) (which I maintain), but <strike>I can't find one for Mojo</strike> there wasn't one for Mojo.

Now there is [Mojo::Log::Colored](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Log::Colored), which can color individual log lines based on their log level.

> ```
> use Mojo::Log::Colored;
>
> # Log to STDERR
> $app->log(
>     Mojo::Log::Colored->new(
>
>         # optionally set the colors
>         colors => {
>             debug => "bold bright_white",
>             info  => "bold bright_blue",
>             warn  => "bold green",
>             error => "bold yellow",
>             fatal => "bold yellow on_red",
>         }
>     )
> );
> ```

This will give you nice colorful output to the console. Here's an example script.

```
$ MOJO_LOG_LEVEL=debug perl -Mojo -MMojo::Log::Colored \
  -e 'a(
      "/" => sub { 
          app->log->$_("hello world") for qw/debug info warn error fatal/;
          shift->render(text=>"ok"); 
      })->log( Mojo::Log::Colored->new )->start' \
  daemon
```

And the output if called with `$ curl localhost:3000`.

[image: console output]